# High-Side Protection IC: what is the Vgs when IC is disabled?

Tags: mosfet, over-voltage-protection, maximum-ratings

I want to use the [LM5060 High-Side Protection IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5060.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1700491067900&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Feu.mouser.com%252F), where you can add an external N-channel enhancement type MOSFET to turn it on/off. I will bias it with 36 V that I need for my PCB.
I try to understand what will the Vgs value be when the IC is off/not-enabled but the 36 V are there. This will be my hookup:

[image: LM5060 when IC is off]

And I don't see anywhere mentioning what the gate pin voltage will be when the EN pin is low. I am afraid when the EN=0V, then that gate pin will bias the MOSFET's gate with 0 V, so I will need to use a MOSFET with \$ V_{GS}~ \pm36V \$ (which are expensive and hard to find for large current draws).
I see the plots show the gate voltage reaching 0 V:

[image: LM5060 Vgs]

While I assume under no circumstances the GATE pin should bias voltage below the ~Vin voltage, because a) it doesn't have to, the N-FET will turn off at VGS=0 V and b) it might go below the N-FET's VGs limit.

I think the whole document assumes that all the Vgate values are measured in reference with the Vsource of the FET and not the GND. After all, in their [LM5060EVAL Evaluation Board](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snva413c/snva413c.pdf?ts=1700482026660) they use a [Mosfet SUM40N10-30](https://www.vishay.com/docs/72134/72134.pdf) with \$ V_{GS}= \pm20V \$ and they allow Vin up to 37 V.

At the end of the day I will try the IC and find out. But I would like to know why, where is it mentioned in the datasheet (and possibly how) is the gate pin biasing the gate with what voltage when EN=0 V and Vin is high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Zero.

The external gates are driven with current, not voltage. A charge-pump-driven current source (I<sub>GATE</sub> = 24uA to the top-left of the block diagram below) drives the output, and an internal zener limits the gate-source voltage to 16.8V. Smaller turn-on current allows the external MOSFET to be used as an inrush limiter by keeping the ohmic-region active for a longer time.

To turn the external MOSFET off, the IC uses two independent current "sinks":

- One for normal off (I<sub>GATE-OFF</sub> = 2.2mA for quicker turn-off),
- One for fault off (I<sub>GATE-FLT</sub> = 80mA for even quicker turn-off).

These can be clearly seen from the block diagram:

[image]

I didn't read the entire datasheet but probably Normal OFF and/or Fault OFF switch(es) remain closed, making the GATE and OUT voltages around zero, therefore V<sub>GS</sub> of the external MOSFET zero.

Comment: I understand, you are right. But can you explain the Evaluation Board's maximum Vin=37V with a Vgs \$ \pm \$ 20V Mosfet? Maybe the evaluation Board has the EN pin tied to Vin with a resistor permanently, but that's not shown in the schematics/layout, the EN pin is left floating for the user to control.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasilis I understand your confusion and concern but the input voltage Vin and gate-source voltage Vgs do not relate to each other. Vgs is the gate voltage w.r.t. source. If the source was grounded and the input could reach 37V then that would be a problem. But the source is at input level i.e. source pin's voltage will be 37V **with respect to ground**. And the gate voltage will be higher than that (thanks to the charge pump) again, **with respect to ground**. But with respect to each other, the ratings will not be exceeded

Comment: Right. I also found in page 21 of datasheet it mentions a Vgs limitation, due to the applied gate voltage when turning on the FET: _If the device chosen for Q1 has a maximum VGS rating less than 16 V, an external zener diode must be added from gate to source to limit the applied gate voltage. The external zener diode forward current rating should be at least 80 mA to conduct the full gate pull-down current during fault conditions_